# Mule4 SFTP List - Not accepting Timestamp

Tags: list, sftp, mule4

I send a ISO-8601 compliant date string as a payload to mule4 SFTP List operation.I get the following error:

```
"\"Unable to convert '2015-06-03T13:21:56+00:00' with class 
'java.lang.String' to class 'LocalDateTime', while writing Java at 
payload.\" evaluating expression: \"payload\"."
```

If I hardcode the same string in SFTP List operation's Timestamp Since the operation works.

Kindly help.

Comment: Please add the complete error message from the log, and the XML of the SFTP list operation hardcoded and the original version. If the timestamp is coming from a variable or payload, add a logger to print the payload in the log before the list.

Comment: Also please mention the version of the SFTP connector.